# os.walk without altering file arrangement

Tags: python, loops, directory, operating-system, os.walk

I am looping through subfolders within a folder using os.walk. I am trying to grab the names of the files within the subfolders. The code works but the issue is it is not printing them the way the files are arranged in my local pc

```
import os
r=[]
def list_file(dir):
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for name in files:
        r.append(name)
return r

list_file(folder)
```

for the first subfolder, I was expecting an arrangement of 153, 154, 157, 158, 159, 160, 249, 250, 298, 302, 308, 357, 361, 376, 377, 380, 472, 473, 562, 755, 925, 926, 1078, 1079, 1080, 1081 but I got 1078, 1079, 1080, 1081 first followed by the rest.
How do I ensure the arrangement isnt altered.

Comment: You probably got alphabetical order instead of numerical order.

Comment: How do you know the order of files in your PC? Usually you use a program which may itself reorder the files by some criterion.

Comment: @wxz I dont  get.
I have this prefix TRAIN IMAGES -NEW before each numerical values

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I am trying to map the file names with my predicted labels. That is why I needed it to be arranged orderly

Comment: @d,b wont that affect the arrangement in the other subfolders. I grabbed all the files in the subfolders and save them into a list. If I sort it, will it sort it per subfolder?

Comment: Right, so alphabetical order wouldn't care about length of name. In alphabetical order `100` comes before `11` because of the second character. Doesn't matter what characters come after. Of course, numerically 11 should be before 100. So you need to look up how to sort the names in numerical order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
from natsort import natsorted

def list_files1(dir):
r = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    j=natsorted(files)
    r.extend(os.path.splitext(name)[0] for name in j)
return r
```